# How to access same service by 2 components?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2. I want to pass data from one component to another using services. I had wrote one main service and setting a data from component1 and fetching it into another component2. It works fine but now I have to again fetch a data into component3, this time I am getting an undefined error. Please help me and Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide the code.

Comment: please provide a plnkr or a minimal example

Comment: Check for imports, providers in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure that the same instance of service is injected into the three components.

if you provide the same instance in two different places angular will create two different instances of that service.
[image]

as you can see the Angular application is a tree of components, each components has an array of providers, angular makes a new instance for each service in the providers array, and provide it for the current components and its children as the image describe.
[image]
when someComponent asks for a service in its constructor, angular create a bubble that goes step by step for parents and ask them if they had an instance of this service, the first instance of this service wons, First-Match-Won strategy.
so you need to make sure that the three components bubbles arrives the same instance of that service.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, if you want to share single instance of a service, add the service in `app.module.ts` `providers`, then in each component's constructor, you can inject that service.

Here's an example of shared service:

**app.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppService{
    myGlobalVar;

    constructor(){
      this.myGlobalVar = true;
      console.log("My global variable value: " + this.myGlobalVar);
      alert("My intial global variable value is: " + this.myGlobalVar);
    }

    setMyGV(val: boolean){
      console.log("Setting FV to: " + val);
      this.myGlobalVar = val;
    }

    getMyGV(val: boolean){
      return this.myGlobalVar;
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [ HeroService, AppService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**dashboard.component.ts:**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

   changeGV(val){
    this.appService.setMyGV(val);
  }

  showGV(){
    alert("GV: " + this.appService.getMyGV());
  }

  showGV(){
    alert("GV: " + this.appService.getMyGV());
  }

}
```

**heroes.component.ts:**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  changeGV(val){
    this.appService.setMyGV(val);
  }

  showGV(){
    alert("GV: " + this.appService.getMyGV());
  }
}
```

[Live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/juF6ICGAqPbXkEHkBuFW?p=info)